# Reddit-Style Nested Comment System

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently using a `ListView` to handle comments in my app, but intend to upgrade it to a **Reddit-Style Nested Comment System** to facilitate discussion. ([Link](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2snxu7/swipe_tabs_in_material_design_how_do_you/))

I am quite at a loss as to how **Comments** nested with **Replies** are implemented in the UI, as well as loading the data seamlessly. Currently I store `pointers` in each `Comment` object to its replies in my **Parse Database**, and am overriding the `getItemViewType()` method in my `Adapter` to achieve a nested view.

However, it seems that this approach is **less than optimal** and takes **too long** to load the comments. Are there any pointers as to a more effective and efficient implementation of this feature?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/roibareket/HierarchicalRecyclerView